# Lightweight / Fast jQuery Modal Window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Looking for a lightweight and fast jQuery modal window - i.e. the jQuery UI modal seems to be large and looking for something light weight ?

Does anyone know of a light-weight jQuery Modal window that's given good / fast performance with ajax etc ?

Answer (score 4):

this is the simplest yet configurable one I've come across: [jQModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).

If you're willing to write you're own AJAX stuff and want a really simple Modal implementation only see: [Soh Tanaka's Simple Modal](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/)

Comment: jQMOdal looks pretty good - i'll check that out thx [will also check out Tanakas :)]

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos) / 
I think this one is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Let's dig up this topic... Some people might be still looking for a lightweight & fast modal jQuery plugin in 2013.*

My favorite lightweight modal plugin for 2013 is [easyModal.js](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/easyModal.js/). It's **only 1.87 KB minified**. It's inspired by leanModal.js, which is also brilliant.